# What are some good mathematical magazines and journals for undergraduates and/or high school students?

Tags: reference-request, education, book-recommendation, big-list

I know only about [Resonance](http://www.ias.ac.in/Journals/Resonance_%E2%80%93_Journal_of_Science_Education/) published by Indian Academy of Sciences and I've read most of the content from it's math portion of all the issues.

Comment: See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36850/journals-for-undergraduates

Answer (score 2):

AMS's journal is better. [John Baez's stuff](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/) is quite interesting site, and I recommend [Qiaochu Yuan's](https://qchu.wordpress.com/reading-recommendations/), too.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not a journal or magazine, Introduction To Modern Mathematics by Helena Rasiowa is a great book. It covers introductory set theory, logic, and a bit of abstract algebra at the end.

It works through the proofs in detail so it is a very friendly read.